# Flutter: Tabs with NestedScrollView and SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

To be brief, I would like this behaviour (mutliple tabs with the appBar hidding when scroll to bottom, and AppBar showing when I scroll to top), and I would like to retain scroll positions for each tabs:

[image: what I want]

I already have all my tabs with a scrollController for each, but if I understand well, to implement the `SliverAppBar`, I need to have only one scroll controller, used in the main `NestedScrollView`, right ?

And a `ScrollController` can only be attached to one `ScrollView`. So how can I manage my ScrollViews ([StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)) to retain my scroll positions ?

I saw the property `ScrollController.positions` and the `PrimaryScrollController` class but I don't know if these are the solutions.

If someone have an idea :)

Comment: also please provide some code so we won't need to start from scratch to help you

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be this package [extended_nested_scroll_view](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view).

Here's how I implemented your wanted scroll-behaviour (multiple tabs with the appBar hiding when scrolling to bottom, and `AppBar` showing when I scroll to top):

(It's not polished but you can work with it)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
        return [SliverAppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          title: Text('Pets'),
          centerTitle: false,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.pets),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        )];
      },
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Dogs',),
              Tab(text: 'Cats'),
              Tab(text: 'Birds'),
            ],
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: Icon(Icons.pets, color: Colors.blue)),
              Center(child: Icon(Icons.pets, color: Colors.green)),
              Center(child: Icon(Icons.pets, color: Colors.red)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

I used a Scaffold inside the `NestedScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar`, with these you get practically 2 individual `AppBar`'s and the `SliverAppBar` hides when scrolling up.
To retain the scroll positions of each Tab I would use 3 independent `ScrollController`. If you need more help with these just write a comment ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I want, and your example works perfectly for a simple tab content. But as soon as I fill the tab with a scrollable, the AppBar doesn't hide anymore. I tried with and without independant ScrollControllers on my tabs, without success (But in all case, I need the ScrollControllers to my "LoadMore" feature, when the user scroll to the bottom)

Comment: yeah I tried it myself after writing this example for you, there's an open issue on Github for this already, best for now is to use the package I linked above.

Comment: Have you tried to provide the NestedScrollView and Tab with the same scrollcontroller?, the only downside would be that each scrollposition doesn't get saved on tabSwitch

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just tried to use the same ScrollController for the NestedScrollView and my ScrollView. To get it working, we need to be on a tab without enough elements to fill the page (without scroll).
I will check the linked package tonight, thanks a lot :)

Comment: So far all given solutions doesn't work, so I can't accept the answer. I just tried with the extended_nested_scroll_view package, but impossible to get it working on the flutter master branch (I need it to resolve another issue :/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224936/discussion-between-nuqo-and-slot).